# Customize read more link in wordpress without page id

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I have been trying to customize a read more link in WordPress and give it a static root folder link like `<a href="%root-directory%/about.php"></a>`.And is it possible to change the static page content from my dashboard. I am a beginner in WordPress.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by filtering the `the_content_more_link` hook, like so:

```
function modify_read_more_link() {
    return '<a class="more-link" href="' . get_permalink() . '">Your Read More Link Text</a>';
}
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'modify_read_more_link' );
```

Add that filter to your **functions.php**.

Comment: Thank you for the example @Melvin Koopmans but I do not figure it out where should I put my root directory location to the href because `get_permalink()` does not give me the actual url.

Comment: @RajeshDey You can get the absolute filesysteem root path with get_home_path()`. That code was just an example, replace the returned value with whatever you want it to link to. May I ask why you want to change the URL this way?

Comment: i want it b/c it is a very simple site, there is hardly chance of any content change. But in future it may needed thats y m tryng to change it from dashboard and it is my first project in wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

No. You should move the file to the theme folder (wp-content/themes/your theme folder). Or create a child theme for your active theme and move the file to that folder.

Comment: I placed the file in the themes folder but how can I add the contents frm the dashboard.

Comment: Can you explain what type of contents that you would like to display in the footer area?

Comment: in footer area there is simple contact details with some social icons, it is a vry simpl web site. just want to display users the full contents of about page, dats it @Dev Kiran

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of design?

Comment: I hav update the question with the screen shoot

Comment: I hope your issue is fixed